# Does nodetool repair repair the next node?

Tags: cassandra

Let's assume we have a Cassandra cluster with the following ring: `A -> B -> C -> D` (no virtual nodes), and we assume that all the data is stored at `RF=2`. Now let's say that `B` dies, leaving us with the following ring `A -> C -> D`. Which means that `C` will need the replica of `A`'s primary range and `D` the replica of `B`'s primary range. (`B`'s primary range do not need to be copied to `C` because `C` already holds a replica).

My questions are the following:

- If I run `nodetool repair` on `C` it will get a copy of `A`'s primary range, but will it stream a copy of `B`'s primary range to `D`?
- If I run `nodetool repair -pr` on `A` will it stream it's primary range to `C`?
- If I run `nodetool repair -pr` on `C` will it stream `B`'s primary range to `D`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked, and answered on StackOverflow, [Clarifications about nodetool repair -pr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013215/clarifications-about-nodetool-repair-pr).

---

To answer this question here, the answers are:

- Yes.
- Yes.
- Yes.